# .NET Windows Service connecting to AWS Simple Queue Service creating high bandwidth use

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, windows-services, amazon-sqs

I have written a windows service on a server which connects to SQS every 20 seconds to check for messages to retrieve and process. I've noticed that the service is using around 30MB of bandwidth per hour, even when there are no messages to receive. It's as though the bandwidth is being used just for the operation of connecting to the SQS queue to check the approximateMessagesVisible count. It seems excessive to me, that it uses so much bandwidth / data just to check the queue. Are there any general recommendations around C# and interacting with SQS that I should be following that could assist with reducing the bandwidth. There are optimisations I can do around sending messages back, but the checking needs to be done frequently, so I'm wondering what actually constitutes the data being used (it's always download, not upload - so data INTO the server running the service, and the only thing it connects to is an SQS queue).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried or thought of writing an AWS Lambda function which can only be triggered once the sqs queue has messages, you wouldn't have to check the queue for messages as soon as there's a message the Lambda function can be triggered and you can put the process that you do with the service to the Lambda function through that way your bandwidth will only be used if there a process happening with the Lambda function

Comment: This is a great solution for inside AWS, but the clients with the service on them are outside AWS, running on physical windows servers. Therefore Lambda is not an option. Instead I use a windows service to do the connection and polling, however we will look to remove this archtiecture inside AWS and replace with a serverless model of SQS onto Lambda (this was only made available in the last few months, so we built auto-scaling small instances each running a windows service that connects to the queues and gets the messages put there by the clients running on physical servers)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the solution - or reason - this was occurring was actually down to the ListQueues command that the service used in order to understand that it had a connection to AWS OK. Because of the hundreds of queues in that account, and the lack of specificity on the command, every connection check was trawling through all 600+ queues as part of the list, which consumed memory and bandwidth as a result.